# How to display data in two columns with PHP "Labels print"?

Tags: php, label

What should I do so that I can not do the following? I want to print out the results as an address label.

1     2

3     4

5     6

7     8

...   ...

[Sample view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vdiS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution echoing html table tags and variables, you could also use css. Some will say css is better, but this sort of tabular arrnagement of data is exactly the reason table tags were designed. $ variable fields will automatically be identified as variables and parsed to the undsrlying inofrmation in memory, so you do not need to concatenate the fields and strings, but it makes the code more precise and readable. You could just embed the variables in the string if you wish.

```
<?php

$c1r1="col1row1";
$c2r1="col2row1";
$c1r2="col1row2";
$c2r2="col2row2";

echo "
<table border \"=2\"> 
<tr><td>". $c1r1."</td><td>".$c2r1."</td></tr>
<tr> <td>".$c1r2."</td> <td>".$c2r2."</td></tr>
</table>";

?>
```

[Reference to official w3 docs on tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)

Comment: I have about 3500 data in my MySQL. Is it the only way to write this?

Comment: Well you can use `foreach` function so you need to add about 3 lines of code to what is above.

Comment: This just an example of the layout, you can use a loop to echo one row at a time. so echo the table tag, then in the loop echo the table rows on each iteration of the loop, at the end of the loop echo the table end tag.

Comment: The posted link is not just a *"discussion"*. It is the page that describes how HTML tables work, from the official HTML 4 standard. Very good reading; it applies to HTML 5 as well.

Comment: True, I will edit to say official docs. I thought it was the best ref.

Comment: The posted code uses "smart quotes". They look nice on printed documents but they are not recognized as quotes in programming. Novice programmers can be misled by this answer. Please replace them with straight quotes (`"`).

Comment: @axiac, I presume you meant the ' around the border parameter. I have replaced with " and escaped. I think it is good practice to enclose in speech marks as per w3 docs, but also most browsers will interpret as a parameter without speech marks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sinan, please upvote or if it has solved you problem mark as solution.

Comment: @Sinan, if you now need help with the for loop, then adapt the code from this solution as best you can to your context and then post another question if yuou hit a snag. Good luck.

Comment: You posted PHP code but the PHP interpreter [doesn't recognize](https://3v4l.org/0UldB) `“` and `”` as quotes and triggers a syntax error several tokens later. You can also see the code is not properly highlighted in the answer.

Comment: @axiac, Thanks, I see what you mean. I answered on my phone using google docs and it used smart quotes. I have just edited using Hackers keyboard and edited in plain text editor. It now runs well https://3v4l.org/deUJV.